# code conversion from C to java

Tags: java, c

I've been trying to convert this code from C to java but haven't been successful mainly because I never learnt C. The for loops are confusing the hell out of me..

```
int a=10000,b,c=2800,d,e,f[2801],g;
main(){
for(;b-c;)f[b++]=a/5;
for(;d=0,g=c*2;c-=14,printf("%.4d",e+d/a),e=d%a)
for(b=c;d+=f[b]*a,f[b]=d%--g,d/=g--,--b;d*=b);
}
```

I saw the code on this site, http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/mathtext/node12.html. Any help would be highly appreciated. In particular the second and third for loops don't have conditional statements where they're supposed to be.

Comment: C is pretty similar to java.. why don't you put some effort in reviewing some C principles?.. if you already know Java, it'll take you no more than an hour

Comment: It seems to access `b` before it is initialized.

Comment: Loops are very similar between Java and C. If you know Java, you'll pick it up very fast

Comment: That's some terrible code to convert. If you need to write a program that calculates pi, better just find the algorithm and write the program from scratch.

Comment: Why would anyone do `for(;b-c;)` as opposed to using a `while` loop?

Comment: Your energy would perhaps be better spent hunting down the author of the code and demanding that they explain themselves. Eeuuw!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Good luck with hunting the author down: Dik Winter died in december 2009 [CWI page on Dik Winter](http://www.cwi.nl/2009/1044/Dik-Winter)

Comment: @AusCBloke: As the page proudly proclaims '160 character C program' and the formatting is atrocious, I guess brevity was considered more important than readability.

Answer (score 4):

In C, for loops can have missing clauses.

If you know this and also know what a `for` is:

```
for ( initialization ; condition ; increase )
{
   code;
}

//is actually

initialization;
while (condition)
{
   increase;
   code;
}
```

it's actually easy:

```
for(;b-c;)f[b++]=a/5;
```

is equivalent to

```
while (b-c)
{
   f[b++] = a/5;
}
```

The second one:

```
for(;d=0,g=c*2;c-=14,printf("%.4d",e+d/a),e=d%a)
```

is equivalent to:

```
while ( d=0, g=c*2 )
{
   //the order in which the following are executed might be different
   c-=14;
   printf("%.4d",e+d/a);
   e=d%a;
}
```

Finally, the third one:

```
for(b=c;d+=f[b]*a,f[b]=d%--g,d/=g--,--b;d*=b);
```

is equivalent to:

```
b=c;
while ( d+=f[b]*a, f[b]=d%--g, d/=g--, --b )
{
   D*=b;
}
```

However, the code is really **really** ugly, you're better off starting from scratch.

EDIT:

One further explanation - for a condition consisting of expressions separated by commas, only the last one relevant to the loop:

```
while ( a, b, c )
{
}
```

will loop until `c` is evaluated to false. However, `a` and `b` are executed at each iteration. So if `c` would be evaluated to `false`, the other expression in the condition statement are still executed, whereas the expressions in the increase statement are not (which is probably the intent here).

Comment: And integers act as booleans, which is not the case in Java. (0 means false in C)

Comment: so does that mean the loop should look like this?
    while(d==0 logical operator g==c*2)
    { 
      c-=14;
      printf("%.4d",e+d/a);
      e=d%a;
    }

Comment: Actually only the last expresion of those separated by commas is relevant to the break condition. Will detail my answer.

Comment: @CoolDude I edited my answer, hope it makes things clearer.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore.. Thanks man.. really appreciate the explanation.

Comment: Isn't the third loop nested inside the second since there's no semicolon or block separating the parenthesis from the second from the `for` keyword?

Comment: @Mike yes it is, but that doesn't change anything.